# PHP - Finding the best combination out of an cartesian product

Tags: php

I'm playing around and trying to get the best possible combination out of an cartesian product.

For each part of the cartesian product you must define, if the highest or the lowest value is the best one.

For example in dataset $a the best value should be the lowest, in $b and $c the best value is the highest.

That's my code so far, but now im stuck

```
<?php

class Optimizer {

// define different sets
public $a = [
    'from' => 1,
    'till' => 10,
    'steps' => 0.5,
    'best' => 'min',
];

public $b = [
    'from' => 20,
    'till' => 40,
    'steps' => 2,
    'best' => 'max',
];

public $c = [
    'from' => 300,
    'till' => 333,
    'steps' => 1,
    'best' => 'max',
];

// get source variable names
public function getSource() {
    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

// generate input data for cartesian product
public function generateOptions() {
    $options = [];

    foreach($this->getSource() as $varName) {
        $data = $this->$varName;
        $options[$varName] = range($data['from'], $data['till'], $data['steps']);
    }

    return $options;
}

// generate cartesian product
public function cartesianProduct() {
    $result = [];
    $options = $this->generateOptions();

    while (list($key, $values) = each($options)) {
        if (empty($values)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (empty($result)) {
            foreach($values as $value) {
                $result[] = [$key => $value];
            }
        }
        else {
            $append = [];

            foreach($result as &$product) {
                $product[$key] = array_shift($values);

                $copy = $product;

                foreach($values as $item) {
                    $copy[$key] = $item;
                    $append[] = $copy;
                }

                array_unshift($values, $product[$key]);
            }

            $result = array_merge($result, $append);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

// get criteria per set
public function getCriterias() {
    $criterias = [];

    foreach($this->getSource() as $varName) {
        $data = $this->$varName;
        $criterias[$varName] = $data['best'];
    }

    return $criterias;
}

// find best possible combination
public function findOptimum() {
    $criterias = $this->getCriterias();
    $combinations = $this->cartesianProduct();

    // ...
}
}
```

any help is welcome, so thank you in advance

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean by "stuck"? What does your code do currently? How is it different from what you want?

Comment: It does nothing. I have absolutely No Idea how to go on.

Comment: From what you've shown here, that makes sense. Defining a class doesn't do anything inherently. Can you show how you're using this class in your main program?

Comment: At the moment it's just something like a prove of concept, so for now, you would use it with `$o = new Optimizer(); $o->findOptimum()´. Later, I'll write a frontend where you can define $a, $b, $c, ... hit a button and the result get's shown.